# Change of winning a lottery with a quota

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to calculate the change of me winning a spot to a race, but I'm not 100% sure about my calculation.

Here's the problem:

> A lottery has 236 spots. At least 15% of them are reserved for women. 3087 applied, 8% women. What’s the change for a women to win a spot and a man to win? The drawing is done by first picking the women; 15% of 236, then they fill up with everyone else.

What I first did is calculating the change of a women to win.

$\frac{(0.15 * 236)} {(3087 * 0.08)} \approx 0.14$

So now I imagen that the women quota as been filled that the remaining people has an equal change of winning.

$\frac{236 * (1 - 0.15)) }{ (3087 - (236 * 0.15))} \approx 0.7$

Here I say that all women from the quota has been picked, which means that $236 * (1 - 0.15)$ spots remains and $(3087 - (236 * 0.15))$ people.

So my answer would be that a women has 7% + 14% change of winning and men 7%.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, "at least 15% of the spots go to women". 15% of 236 is 35.4. "At least 15%" means "at least 35.4" which means 36. Your calculation must be done with 36 spots for women, and 200 for men.

8% of 3087 is 246.96. Clearly there are not 246.96 women. We can try to make assumptions: For example that there are 247 women, or between 7.5% and 8.5% (from 232 to 262). Let's assume 247 women.

For a woman the chance to get a spot is 36/247 ≈ 14.57%. For a man the chance is 200/2840 ≈ 7.04%.

Your mistake is to assume that women can get more spots after they have received the "at least 15%" quota. They don't.

Comment: They can get more then 15% of the spots and they did. The drawing was done 1h ago and women got 21%.